# Highchart range selector right align

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On the following [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/71t5pjnL/), I disable the 'context menu' using following code:

```
 exporting: { enabled: false }
```

I was hoping that the text boxes will be right align automatically. But its not the case there is padding/space. I want the text boxes right align.

The strange part is if you add the title/subtitle to the chart then the text boxes get right align.

```
subtitle: { text: 'the subtitle' }
```

But I don't want to have the title/subtitle.

Comment: Looks like a bug - issue reported: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5165 Until fix you could use Kishor's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is strange, since it is working if there is a `title` or `subtitle`. I have played around with the options provided in the documentation, [`RangeSelector`'s `inputPosition`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputPosition) worked,

```
inputPosition: {
    x: 0
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71t5pjnL/2/).

Answer (score 0):

When the context menu is disabled and subtitle enabled it's using inline styling `transform="translate(424,39)"` to position the From - To date boxes in a `<g>` element (with `class="highcharts-input-group"`)

But when you disable the subtitle it gets `transform="translate(384,39)` allowing 40px on the right for the context menu (even if `exporting: { enabled: false }`)

So write a small function to access that `<g>` element through its className and modify that inline style by changing the  `transform="translate(384,39)"` into `transform="translate(424,39)"`